# Map array within array from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, map-function

So my code is:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

        this.state = {

            myArray: [
                {id:1, continent:[
                    {id:1, name: 'Russia'},
                    {id:2, name: 'Germany'},
                    {id:3, name: 'Poland'}
                ]},

                {id:2, continent:[
                    {id:1, name: 'China'},
                    {id:2, name: 'India'},
                    {id:3, name: 'Bangladesh'}
                ]},

                {id:3, continent:[
                    {id:1, name: 'Brazil'},
                    {id:2, name: 'Peru'},
                    {id:3, name: 'Chile'}
                ]}      
            ],

            otherValue: 23
        }
    }


    subBoardList(id){
        return this.state.myArray[id].map((continent) => {
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>{continent.name}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        })
    }


  render() {
    return (
      {this.subBoardList(2)}
    );
  }
}
```

I want to display the content of the continent array of which id is passed to the `subBoardList` function. How do I do that?

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.myArray[id].map')
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using:

```
this.state.myArray[id].continent.map(...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

            this.state = {

                myArray: [
                    {id:1, continent:[
                        {id:1, name: 'Russia'},
                        {id:2, name: 'Germany'},
                        {id:3, name: 'Poland'}
                    ]},

                    {id:2, continent:[
                        {id:1, name: 'China'},
                        {id:2, name: 'India'},
                        {id:3, name: 'Bangladesh'}
                    ]},

                    {id:3, continent:[
                        {id:1, name: 'Brazil'},
                        {id:2, name: 'Peru'},
                        {id:3, name: 'Chile'}
                    ]}      
                ],

                otherValue: 23
            }
        }


        subBoardList(id){
            return this.state.myArray[id].continent.map((continent) => {
                // You need to add continent key after myArray since
                // index 2 = {id:3, continent:[
                //    {id:1, name: 'Brazil'},
                //    {id:2, name: 'Peru'},
                //    {id:3, name: 'Chile'}
                //]} 

                return(
                    <View>
                        <Text>{continent.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                )
            })
        }


      render() {
        return (
          <div> {this.subBoardList(2)} </div>
         // Add a div after return it's import to render anything
        );
      }
    }
```

**Try like this.**

Comment: Have look at this codesandbox snippet (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-viewer-demo-inline-emrxp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by id and id is not behave as an index, for example, id can be any number(10,11,12 or 120,155,254...), your `subBoardList` should be like this

```
 subBoardList(id) {
    return this.state.myArray.map(item => {

      if (item.id === id) {

        return item.continent.map(c => { return <li> {c.name} </li>; });

                           } 
      else return null;
    });
  }
```

[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-moore-hxpuu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)